# How to plot a certain function on a certain interval (many functions)

Tags: plotting

so I'm trying to make natural cubic splines for:

$$f(x) = e^x$$

Anyway, I've already set the conditions, etc. All I want to do is plot the spline so it looks neat. So in the image, for example, I want to graph S0(x) from [0, 1], S1(x) from [1,2] and S2(x) from [2, 3].

```
S0[x_] = 2.718281828459045 + 
   2.2228502570276887*(x - 1) + (0.7568526428529632)*(x - 
      1)^2 + (0.252284214284321)*(x - 1)^3;
S1[x_] = 7.389056098930651 + 8.809769654506471*(x - 2) + 
   5.830066754625819*(x - 2)^2 + 1.6910713705909515*(x - 2)^3;
S2[x_] = 20.085536923187668 + 14.63983640913229*(x - 3) + 
   0*(x - 3)^2 + (-1.943355584875273)*(x - 3)^3;
Plot[{S0[x], S1[x], S2[x], E^x}, {x, 0, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: My current plot]

Comment: `Plot[{ConditionalExpression[S0[x], 0 <= x <= 1], 
  ConditionalExpression[S1[x], 1 <= x <= 2], 
  ConditionalExpression[S2[x], 2 <= x <= 3], E^x}, {x, 0, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: `S[x_] = Piecewise[{{S0[x], 0 <= x < 1}, {S1[x], 1 <= x < 2}, {S2[x], 2 <= x <= 3}}]; Plot[S[x], {x, 0, 3}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Condition` ,`/;` is another way which does not change the expression of `PlotLegends`

```
Clear["`*"]; 
S0[x_] := 
 2.718281828459045 + 
   2.2228502570276887*(x - 
      1) + (0.7568526428529632)*(x - 1)^2 + (0.252284214284321)*(x - 
       1)^3 /; 0 <= x <= 1;
S1[x_] := 
  7.389056098930651 + 8.809769654506471*(x - 2) + 
    5.830066754625819*(x - 2)^2 + 1.6910713705909515*(x - 2)^3 /; 
   1 <= x <= 2;
S2[x_] := 
  20.085536923187668 + 14.63983640913229*(x - 3) + 
    0*(x - 3)^2 + (-1.943355584875273)*(x - 3)^3 /; 2 <= x <= 3;

Plot[{S0[x], S1[x], S2[x]}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```